# 1D convolution in each row of an image in the x-direction

Tags: c++, vtk, convolution, itk

I would like to calculate a 1D convolution in each row of an image in the x-direction.

For that I am trying to use the example shown at http://www.na-mic.org/svn/Slicer3-lib-mirrors/trunk/Insight/Examples/Filtering/LaplacianRecursiveGaussianImageFilter1.cxx

It produces an exception when I try to ‘update’ the last filter. It is a “stack overflow” and it goes to “itkObject.cxx”  don’t know what I am doing wrong because I just copied the code in the example.

Another thing and more important is that I have found a lot of information about convolution but nothing specific for doing this 1D convolution in each row of an image in the x-direction. Is there another better example to have a look? A better class to use?

Answer (score 1):

You could setup your own 1D kernel and then use this:
http://www.itk.org/Wiki/ITK/Examples/Images/NeighborhoodOperatorImageFilter

Also, here is a working example of LaplacianRecursiveGaussianImageFilter:
http://www.itk.org/Wiki/ITK/Examples/EdgesAndGradients/LaplacianRecursiveGaussianImageFilter